# Unable to fetch data from tmdb javaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I am trying to build a movie web using tmdb api, JavaScript, css and html only. I tried to perform search query and show the results but the problem is that the results don't show up. When debugging, the status code received is `200` but when `res.json()` returns it just ends the fetch function and is not moving forward to the data. I will truly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

**My url**

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
const API_KEY = "api_key=9b62c3eb4a6bc8acd4e26602f16fa744";
let SEARCH_URL = BASE_URL + "search/movie?" + API_KEY + "&sort_by=popularity.desc&query=";
```

**My search function:**

```js
function searchMovie() {
    let f = document.getElementById('search_movie');
    f.addEventListener('submit', () => {
        let user_input = search_input.value;
        if (user_input && user_input.trim() != '') {
            let query = SEARCH_URL + user_input;
            console.log();
            getMovies(query);
        }
    });
}
```

**My fetch function:**

```js
function getMovies(my_api) {
    main.innerHTML = '';
    fetch(my_api, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        let arr = data.results;
        if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
            arr.forEach(movie => {
                addMovie(movie);
            });
        }
        else {
            getMovies(MOVIE_URL, DEFAULT_PAGE);
            console.log("Can't find results");
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] (you should be able to remove all the DOM manipulation, add additional logging, trigger it immediately instead of waiting for a submit event, and turn it into a live demo using the stack snippets feature of the question editor (which also has a button that will clean up your broken indentation and make the code much more readable).

Comment: `headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` — You can't put a body on a GET request so why are you claiming that it has a JSON body?

Comment: `credentials: "same-origin",`  — This is the default. Why are you setting it explicitly?

Comment: Hey I deleted it . I tried to add it because I thought that could help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to perofrm movie search but sadly it is not worling. I am trying to enter some input but it does nothing the screen just refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You were mostly there. The fetch call returns a promise, so you shouldn't set `innerHTML` to that.  Instead, use the promise to wait for the fetch to complete, then update the dom with the result.

I also suggest separating the request and the dom manipulation as I've done below.  It works...

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
const API_KEY = "api_key=9b62c3eb4a6bc8acd4e26602f16fa744";
let SEARCH_URL = BASE_URL + "search/movie?" + API_KEY + "&sort_by=popularity.desc&query=";

function getMovies(my_api) {
  return fetch(my_api, {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: "no-cache",
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
}

function renderMovies(res) {
  let ul = document.getElementById('results');
  ul.innerHTML = '';
  res.results.forEach(result => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.title));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}

let f = document.getElementById('search_movie');
f.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let user_input = search_input.value;
  if (user_input && user_input.trim() != '') {
    let query = SEARCH_URL + user_input;
    getMovies(query).then(renderMovies)
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="search_input"></input><br/>
<button id="search_movie">SEARCH</button><br/>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```